# how to parse google weather xml using XMLParser

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, weather

i want to parse google weather API using NSXML so please guide me for this.  URL looks like: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=islamabad. I can parse data from "tagged" xml, but the xml structure used in this URL is not understandable to me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check docs for NSXMLParserDeleagte:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

attributeDict - is exactly what you need. For example for tag:

```
<weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
```

attributeDict would contain 6 keys: module_id, tab_id, mobile_row, mobile_zipped, row, section with appropriate values.